# Where should a custom Netbeans Platform conf. file be so that maven finds it?

Tags: maven, netbeans-platform

Applications built on top of the NetBeans platform have a `<myappdir>/etc/<myapp>.conf` file determining, among other things, application JVM parameters. Historically, this file was a part of the NetBeans IDE installation (as far as I could tell), but starting with NB 6.9, custom files are now [supported](http://blogs.oracle.com/geertjan/entry/support_for_custom_configuration_files).

I am having trouble packaging a custom configuration file using Maven to build the application.

I imagine the `app.conf` property should have been set in the project's pom under project/build/pluginManagement/plugins like so:

```
<plugin>
 ...
    <configuration>
        <brandingToken>${brandingToken}</brandingToken>
        <cluster>${brandingToken}</cluster>
        <appConf>myapp.conf</appConf>
    </configuration>
```

The maven module representing my application contained no prior source, so I created the `src/main/nbm` folder and placed `myapp.conf` in `src/main/nbm`. This isn't picked up by nbm-maven-plugin. and putting the conf file into `src/main/resources` doesn't make a difference.

So, can anyone explain how a NetBeans Platform application with a custom configuration file can be built using maven?

**UPDATE**:

With Tim's prod in the right direction, I found the answer documented on [Geertjan's blog](http://blogs.oracle.com/geertjan/entry/nimbus_look_and_feel_for). The solution is to configure the nbm-maven-plugin like so in the `application` module pom:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>nbm-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <etcConfFile>src/main/resources/my.conf</etcConfFile>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

BTW, if you need a second name with Geertjan, you're not really a NetBeans platform developer. ;)

Comment: agree 100% with the Geertjan comment, his blog is a treasure trove of NetBeans platform information. Also don't forget the NetBeans Platform Developer Mailing List - dev@platform.netbeans.org

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the documentation of the [nbm:cluster-app](http://mojo.codehaus.org/nbm-maven-plugin/cluster-app-mojo.html) plugin, specifically the part on the [conf file](http://mojo.codehaus.org/nbm-maven-plugin/cluster-app-mojo.html#etcConfFile).

As per my understanding that should allow you to replace the default one with a custom one that you create.