# How can I set VM options in a Java Netbeans Platform Modular Project?

Tags: java, memory, netbeans, jvm, platform

I have a Netbeans Platform modular project, not a regular Java project. I want to set VM options to increase memory, but under the "properties" dialog, there is no way to do this for a modular Netbeans platform project. This has cost me huge amounts of time and I still have not found a good way to set the VM args.

Does anyone know how to set VM args using a Netbeans platform modular project, when compiling and running the program in Netbeans 7? Given the amount of trouble, I am almost ready to give up on Netbeans to create modular applications.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is quite easy, in fact. Just modify **project.properties** file to include the following line:

*Edited:*

```
run.args.extra=-J-Xmx768m
```

Of course, you can include any other JVM options there.

Enjoy.

Comment: When I try this by adding the run.args.extra option that you specify, I get this error: "Ignored unknown option: -Xmx768m"

Comment: Sorry, missed the -J prefix :(

Comment: What if you have more than one argument to pass to jvm? multiple lines or spaces between each entry?

Comment: @J.B - I don't suppose you would know a way to set up environment variables in a "NetBeans Platform" app as well :)

Comment: @simgineer I'm afraid you would need to use os specific launcher scripts to do that.

Comment: ...or use `run.jvmargs=` property

Comment: `run.args.extra` only works in development, see http://forums.netbeans.org/topic5312.html

Comment: Yeah it only works in development, when I install my program with installer it uses Xms24m Xmx64m. Anyone knows how to increase in installer or?

Answer (score 8):

I was finally able to solve this based on information at https://web.archive.org/web/20130830023832/http://activeintelligence.org/blog/archive/gephi-increasing-xmx-memory-in-netbeans/

What I did was modify the project.properties file, as JB said, but the correct way to do it was to add a -J before the args. E.g.,

```
run.args.extra=-J-Xms256m -J-Xmx756m
```

That did it! Not sure why it took 3 months to figure that out. Definitely a fail for the Netbeans documentation. They should really make this editable from the properties menu instead of making users hunt through nondescript config files!

Comment: Nope, the answer - as far as I can tell - only applies to Ant-based projects in NetBeans IDE.

Comment: Sounds like it's unknown as to how we do this in maven? We have an ant project and need to convert it to a maven project. So definitely have to figure out the maven way too.

Comment: @simgineer did you find a way for maven project?

Answer (score 5):

I thought i'll put some contribution on this topic, When I was developing a **netbeans platform application** i also faced the same problem, I added run.args.extra=-J-Xmx768m
and updated my **project.properties** file but it didn't ! But when i added run.args.extra=-J-Xmx768m in my **platform.properties** file then it worked, again this only works when i was in development environment. When I packeged the application for windows the problem remained same my min heap size was 24m and max is 64m. Then I found out that if I update and add default_options="--branding my_project -J-Xms64m -J-Xmx1G" in **my_project.conf** in my installed directory C:\Program Files\my_project\etc then run my application and checked the ide log i can now see the change. By the way i wasn't lucky enough to see even the run node when i right click and go to the project properties dialogue in netbeans 7.0.1. Its upto netbeans dream team to make us feel lucky.

Comment: default_options="--branding my_project -J-Xms64m -J-Xmx1G" in my_project.conf in my installed directory C:\Program Files\my_project\etc then run my application and checked the ide log i cant now see the change.this option is not work for License version of Windows 7.because when i change from "--branding my_project -J-Xms24m -J-Xmx64m" to "--branding my_project -J-Xms64m -J-Xmx1G",it will give warning and not upadated.means i cant change at this path  C:\Program Files\my_project\etc .so any other option?

Comment: Any other option for giving more heap memory at making installer of (My App which is done as netbeans platform modulars project) netbeans platform App in netbeans IDE.

Answer (score 3):

I had this issue and after some digging around and reading a lot of docs I was able to deduce that most of those values were coming from templates in the harness.

So if you go to your IDE_home/harness/etc/ you will find the "app.conf" file. This file is renamed during a distro build and the "app.conf" becomes your "application name.conf". Edit this file with the default values you would like in you application.

In my case I replaced the line that read: 
default_options="--branding ${branding.token} -J-Xms24m -Xmx64m"
with
default_options="--branding ${branding.token} -J-Xms64m -Xmx512m" as my application was needing more memory. By changing the template I dont have to touch every deployment and change the memory CLI for the VM.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thansk a lot, that what i was looking for for a while

Comment: Thanks a lot, was looking for this!

Answer (score 2):

#### For maven projects:

As described in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6558551/where-should-a-custom-netbeans-platform-conf-file-be-so-that-maven-finds-it), you can use [etcConfFile](http://mojo.codehaus.org/nbm-maven/nbm-maven-plugin/cluster-app-mojo.html#etcConfFile) parameter of [nbm-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/nbm-maven/nbm-maven-plugin/):

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>nbm-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <etcConfFile>src/main/resources/app.conf</etcConfFile>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

More info: [Geertjan's Blog](https://blogs.oracle.com/geertjan/entry/nimbus_look_and_feel_for)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use Netbeans to set the VM options without bothering about which file to edit, here we go:

```
Run -> Set project configuration -> VM Options
```

Add your option in the corresponding text box for example: -Xms10m

To answer `user1156544` doubt:

[image]

Comment: I dont see this option, just a selection between default and a release-profile

Answer (score 1):

you have to add these lines to your project properties file.

```
<target name="build-launchers" depends="suite.build-launchers">
<replace file="build/launcher/etc/${app.name}.conf" token="--branding graphsimulator -J-Xms24m -J-Xmx64m" value="--branding graphsimulator -J-Xms128m -J-Xmx512m"/>
</target>
```

Comment: Exactly which file?

Comment: Thanks, I found it, build.xml.