# How to increase Heap memory of Netbeans platform's Application in java?

Tags: java, netbeans, platform, heap-memory

I m making Desktop Application in netbeans plpatform in java swing.when i run my App in netbeans 7.0 it work well.after that i made installer of my app.then i install my App installer, it work very slow.when my App run on netbeans IDE it consume minimum 10mb and maximum 510mb.but after it install it get only 24mb minimum and 64mb maximum byDefault of installer in netbeans IDE or when i make installer of my app using netbeans IDE it get only 24mb minimum and 64mb maximum. so how can i increase Heap memory of my App or heap memory of my app installer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

if you go to your applications installed directory the go to etc folder then open the applicationName.conf file and change the min and max heapsize then save and restart your application, that should change your applications heap size, check the change in your application ide log, thanks

Comment: this done.but my App is save in "C:/ProgramFiles/MyApp/etc/MyApp.config" this path. and when i m go to this path for change heap memory,i got warring. so first of all i have to change the user permision and then i can change heap memory into my app.config file.now i want to make batch or bash or executable file which change permision of user and chnge config file when i run this file.so how to make this file for windows?

Comment: Perfect, this is what i have been looking for since 2 days

Answer (score 6):

Go to your project's properties (right-click on left hand side of the Netbeans interface), and change the VM options field to this:

The 64 is the minimum VM size (in MB) and the 2048 is the maximum VM size in MB.

[image]

Comment: this is help full for app which was made simple java Application. but i made App in netbeans platform. this option is not given to netbeans platform app.thanks for reply.

Comment: Did you try this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6647275/how-can-i-set-vm-options-in-a-java-netbeans-platform-modular-project?rq=1 ?

Comment: i seen that link , but it is useless.because i tried all option which were defined in that link, and did not work that option.so, any other idea?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like from version 6.0+, netbeans auto-defines -Xmx value to be 1/3rd of available memory, as specified in official wiki here:

http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqSettingHeapSize

Status bar should show used memory. Do you find it locked far less than what you could expect, say 33% of max?

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem as yours.
Change the memory setting on that config file: `C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.0\harness\etc\app.conf`