# what is vm option in netbeansproject properties?

Tags: java, tomcat, netbeans

what is vm option in Netbeans ?
what is the meaning of each variable and memmory size of following line

```
-Xms128m -Xmx128m -XX:PermSize=64m -XX:MaxPermSize=128m
```

I got this line from stack-overflow troubling with permgen-space

any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The flag `Xmx` specifies the maximum memory allocation pool for a `Java Virtual Machine` (`JVM`), while `Xms` specifies the initial memory allocation pool.

This means that your `JVM` will be started with `Xms` amount of memory and will be able to use a maximum of `Xmx` amount of memory.

The `Xms` flag has no default value, and `Xmx` typically has a default value of 256MB.

**more information** [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14763079/what-are-the-xms-and-xmx-parameters-when-starting-jvms)

**-XX:PermSize -XX:MaxPermSize** are used to set size for `Permanent Generation`.

`Permanent Generation`: The `Permanent Generation` is where class files are kept. These are the result of compiled classes and `jsp` pages. If this space is full, it triggers a Full Garbage Collection. If the Full `Garbage Collection` cannot clean out old unreferenced classes and there is no room left to expand the Permanent Space, an Out‐of‐ Memory error (`OOME`) is thrown and the `JVM` will crash.

**More information** [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12114174/what-does-xxmaxpermsize-do)

Starting with **Java 8**, both the `permgen` space and this setting are gone.

For netbeans options, have a look [here](https://performance.netbeans.org/howto/jvmswitches/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6647275/how-can-i-set-vm-options-in-a-java-netbeans-platform-modular-project)

Answer (score 0):

please go through this , hope this help you
http://javaeesupportpatterns.blogspot.in/2011/08/java-heap-space-hotspot-vm.html

Answer (score 0):

-Xms128m -Xmx128m -XX:PermSize=64m -XX:MaxPermSize=128m

Above your command is simply ignore the default VM(Vritual Machine) settings and overwrite your customize memory settings to netbeans.

The flag Xmx specifies the maximum memory allocation pool for a Java Virtual Machine (JVM), while Xms specifies the initial memory allocation pool.

This means that your JVM will be started with Xms amount of memory and will be able to use a maximum of Xmx amount of memory. For example, starting a JVM like below will start it with 256MB of memory, and will allow the process to use up to 2048MB of memory:

```
java -Xmx2048m -Xms256m
```

The memory flag can also be specified in multiple sizes, such as kilobytes, megabytes, and so on.

```
-Xmx1024k
-Xmx512m
-Xmx8g
```

The Xms flag has no default value, and Xmx typically has a default value of 256MB. A common use for these flags is when you encounter a java.lang.OutOfMemoryError.

**JVM PermGen**

Sun JVM’s has a concept of PermGen space that is a *seperate* allocated memory region that is used for e.g. allocating classes. This is actually the memory region most people have issues with and not so much the normal heap space, but as a normal user one have a hard time realizing this when eclipse (or rather the jvm) just says “Out of Memory” or simply just crashes.

The solution for this is to add a MaxPermSize value to the vmargs. e.g. I normally use -XX:MaxPermSize=128m to make sure I don’t run out of PermGen space.