# How do I control Java heap size for projects being run under NetBeans?

Tags: java, netbeans, heap-memory

How do I control the heap allocation (`-J-Xmx` aka `-mx`) set for Java instances that NetBeans launches when I `Run` my own code?

(I have already adjusted NetBeans' own heap usage.)

I found this screenshot in [a related thread from June 2016](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/37667413/edit), which shows a Properties dialog containing a ***VM Options*** field:

[image: ohai]

I also found a couple of questions with text answers describing the same process as the screenshot above:

- [How to increase the java heap size in netbeans?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15460779/how-to-increase-the-java-heap-size-in-netbeans)
- [How to increase java heap memory in netbeans?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39764189/how-to-increase-java-heap-memory-in-netbeans)

However, something has changed between NetBeans 8.1 (there's an extra screenshot in the other thread showing the author is using 8.1) and NetBeans 8.2 (the version I am using). I see this instead when I select "Properties" from my project's right-click menu:

[image: ohi]

It looks so different I'm concerned I'm doing something incorrectly.

None of the other tabs have anywhere to input commandline parameters.

The Java Sources, Java Sources Classpath and Output tabs all have this warning at the bottom, though:

[image: hiii]

I've had a look at the sea of XML (and .properties) files in the project and source directories but I didn't find anywhere (obvious) to put launch parameters.

Thanks so much in advance! Hopefully this isn't a case of missing/misunderstanding something utterly trivial!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was using a "modular project", not a standard Java project. (TIL. I might explore seeing if I can switch project types.)

I need to edit project.properties as per this answer:

[How can I set VM options in a Java Netbeans Platform Modular Project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6647275/how-can-i-set-vm-options-in-a-java-netbeans-platform-modular-project)